# react native component as logical condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am looking at a repo that has a render statement with a conditional that has actual components as logical conditions.

```
return <Component>
    {
       this.state.loading == true && 
       <ActivityIndicator 
          animating={this.state.loading} 
       /> ||
       <View>
           ...
       </View>
    }
</Component>
```

I am interpreting it as, 'if state is loading' AND this call to reactDOM.render() returns something OR this call to reacDOM.render() returns something, then...

but the THEN is getting me. Then what?

Is this some sort of ternary? What are the curly brackets inside of `Component`? Where is the result of the condition specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

It's a language feature of javascript. When chaining expressions with `&&` and `||` it will be always the last value returned, that is evaluated. Python does the same with `and` and `or` operators. Some other languages like e.g. PHP always return a boolean value.

In fact that means:

> **`expr1 && expr2`**
>
> Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.
>
> **`expr1 || expr2`**
>
> Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true.

Furthermore the `&&` has precedence over `||` which means that `a || b && c` is equivalent to `a || (b && c)`.

Your example just chains two of these together leading to: "If `this.state.loading` is truthy return `<ActivityIndicator>` else return `<View>`". This abuses the fact, that `null`, `undefined`, `true` and `false` are valid nodes that do not actually render anything for conditional rendering.